# How do I keep my elements/images from moving when I resize my web browser?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to keep all of my elements centered in my page, but whenever I resize my web browser everything turns into a squashed mess. I've been trying to deal with this problem for a couple of days now, but nothing I've done seems to work. I've looked at a lot of sources to see what the problem is (looking up youtube tutorials, making sure all my measurements were in pixels, using wrappers, etc). I'm new to coding (only about a month in), so I'm most definitely overlooking something.

[This is how I want my website to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yphqi.png)

[This is an example of how my website looks when the page is resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuoqF.png)

Here's my HTML:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>J and R Rentals</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class= "body">


<div class="top-container">
  <div id="wrapper">
  <h1 class="title">J and R Rentals</h1>
    <p class="motto">Tired of old broken down rentals? You deserve to rent a brand new one.</p>
    <img class="trees-one" src="002-rural-1.png" alt="">
    <img class="trees-two" src="001-rural.png" alt="">
    <img class="clouds-one" src="clouds.png" alt="">
    <img class="clouds-two" src="clouds.png" alt="">
    <img class="mountain-one" src="mountain.png" alt="">
    <img class="trees-three" src="001-rural.png" alt="">
    <img class="forest-one" src="forest.png" alt="">
    <img class="house-one" src="residential.png" alt="">
    <img class="house-two" src="residential-1.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's my CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  background-color: #cffffe;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 400px;
}

.body {
  margin: 0;
}

.title {
  color: #0f4c75;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 350px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.motto {
  color: #0f4c75;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 350px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.trees-one {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 343px;
  width: 300px;
}

.trees-two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 343px;
  right: 0px;
}

.clouds-one {
position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 200px;
}

.clouds-two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 40px;
  right: 200px;
}

.mountain-one {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 343px;
  right: 300px;
}

.trees-three {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 343px;
  left: 300px;
}

.house-one {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 343px;
  left: 600px;
}

.house-two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 343px;
  right: 600px;
}

.forest-one {
  position: absolute;
  width: 355px;
  bottom: 343px;
  right: 800px;
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help I can get; thank you in advance!

Comment: ok thats hard to recreate. can you please post this as one code snipet? You can edit the html and css in both windows at the same time. also for pictures currently use the full url so we can see them ehre too. Last but not least, get rid of <body class="XY">. Its a bad habit to give the body a class. you can adress the body directly in css just remove the dot befor body in css

Comment: What I do in this kind of stuff is to recreate image on server side with text within it, and calling new image on image source.

Comment: well the problem is the width.the images creating a fixed width that every screen  must have. To my calculation 1155px. Most screens will not fullfill that requirement. Therefor I would place those images into a cenetred box with that exact width and use overflow-x:none to remove the scrollbar. that way you create at least some kind of responsive design

Comment: Have you tried adding the "viewport" meta tag to your HTML head? Here is a link describing it. It pretty much tries to handle the element resizing for you. You may have to tweak some of your CSS when you add this but it really helps with this kind of stuff. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score -1):

check out this site: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

In essence, you can set a **max/min width/height** for the items on your screen to re-adjust.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Your images are set using px at a defined size, so as the window width shrinks, they stay the same causing overlapping and that 'squashed' look

Using vw (view width), you can get the browser to resize each image to a percentage of the width of the current window width (1vw is 1% of width, 67vw is 67% of width)

You can also position them at a percentage point of the current width using vw (20vw to the left or right etc) and the browser repositions them accordingly

Using z-index, you can layer each image on top of each other, (z-index:0 is at the back, z-index:1...2...3 sits on front, the higher the number ,they will be in front of the lower number

Here is an example of using vw for image size and position and using z-index to position them on top of each other.

For this to work you need to wrap all elements in a wrapper with relative position for all the absolute positioning to function within that wrapper, just make the wrapper your whole page size, or whatever you need ;)

Check out my codepen example: [layering and autowidth](https://codepen.io/___ray___/pen/LYNNBQQ)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="title">J and R Rentals</h1>
  <p class="motto">Tired of old broken down rentals? You deserve to rent a brand new one.</p>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/10/200/300" class="img1 all">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/10/200/300" class="img2 all">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/11/200/300" class="img3 all">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/11/200/300" class="img4 all">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/12/200/300" class="img5 all">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/12/200/300" class="img6 all">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/13/200/300" class="img7 all">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/13/200/300" class="img8 all">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  height:200px;
  background-color:lightBlue;
}
.title, .motto{
  z-index:3;
  color:#2333a7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #fff;
  font-family:arial;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:2.8vw;
}
.motto{
  top:30%;
  font-size:1.7vw;
}
.all{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  bottom:0;
}
.img1{
  width:8vw;
  left:38vw;
  height:90%;
}
.img2{
  width:8vw;
  right:38vw;
  height:90%;
}
.img3{
  z-index:2;
  width:20vw;
  left:22vw;
  height:70%;
}
.img4{
  z-index:2;
  width:20vw;
  right:22vw;
  height:70%;
}
.img5{
  width:8vw;
  left:10vw;
  height:80%;
}
.img6{
  width:8vw;
  right:10vw;
  height:80%;
}
.img7{
  z-index:0;
  width:42vw; 
  left:6vw;
  height:60%;
}
.img8{
  z-index:0;
  width:42vw; 
  right:6vw;
  height:60%;
}
```